# Match node that might be the root

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to match a node in xslt that might be the root element or might be a child of the root element.  Is that possible?

Here's one sample file where I would need to match the `Package` element at the root.

```xml
<Package>
  <Target>Tablet</Target>
  <Type>DeviceApp</Type>
  <Name>MyName</Name>
  <Version>1.2.3</Version>
  <Description>My Description</Description>
  <UnneededElmt></UnneededElmt>
</Package>

<!-- Expected result: -->
<Target>Tablet</Target>
<Type>DeviceApp</Type>
<Name>MyName</Name>
<Version>1.2.3</Version>
<Description>My Description</Description>
```

And here's another sample where I need to match the `Package` element at a child level.

```xml
<testcase-root>
  <Package>
    <Target>Tablet</Target>
    <Type>DeviceApp</Type>
    <Name>MyName</Name>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
    <Description>My Description</Description>
    <UnneededElmt></UnneededElmt>
  </Package>
</testcase-root>

<!-- Expected result: -->
<testcase-root>
  <Target>Tablet</Target>
  <Type>DeviceApp</Type>
  <Name>MyName</Name>
  <Version>1.2.3</Version>
  <Description>My Description</Description>
</testcase-root>
```

For the first case, this transform does what I need:

```xml
<xsl:template match="/" >
  <xsl:copy-of select="//Package/*[not(self::UnneededElmt)]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

And for the second one, it works with `<xsl:template match="//Package" >`.  But I need a match that will cover both cases (or a definitive "no, not possible" :)).

Comment: Are you sure you want the result shown in your 1st case? It is an XML fragment, with no single root element.

Comment: The expected result in your first example is not valid XML as there is no root node.  Did you omit the enclosing `<testcase-root>` element?

Comment: Yes, it's not valid xml, but the end result is it being pulled into another xml file, so both of those expected results are correct.

Comment: Are there, besides testcase-root, other root-nodes that should be in the result?

Comment: Theoretically no, but I'd rather not hard code that if possible.  There will only be one root node per input file, but it's not guaranteed to be `testcase-root`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Package">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="UnneededElmt"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```